# How can I check how many connections are in a Group in my Azure SignalR service?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, xamarin.ios, azure-signalr

I am trying to implement Azure SignalR Service to facilitate two way messaging between a desktop, asp.net-core and a xamarin.ios apps.

I have created a `Hub` as per Microsoft's documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Hub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

I add users's connections to a group when they connect to the hub as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Add to Group:

```
public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
}

public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has left the group {groupName}.");
}
```

When a message is sent it has a group name as a parameter, I would like to check if the provided group has any connections before sending the message to any registered clients, if there are no connections, I would like to send a push notification (already have working code for the push notification)

Send Message with Notification Fallback:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendMessage(string groupName, string user, string message)
    {
        var group = Clients.Group(groupName);

        // todo: how to check if we have any open connections in this group?
        if(group.Conections.Count > 0)
        {
            return group.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
        else
        {
            // todo: run code to send push notification or anything else you might want to do
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I don't see any way to check for the number of connections currently in a group via the available api *(correct me if I'm wrong)*

I see the group coming back as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.GroupProxy<ChatHub>` at runtime with no public methods. Internal private variables do include `_groupName` and `_lifeTimeManager` and within lifetime manager there is a `_clientConnectionManager` which i can see has client connections when they are connected but I have no access to any of these, I'm using the `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR` (1.0.4) Nuget package. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do possible with this SDK and if so how I can do this?

Comment: looks like a REST Api endpoint was just recently added to be able to do such a check as described here https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/swagger/v1.md#get-check-if-there-are-any-client-connections-inside-the-given-group

Comment: Probably need to do a mapping exercise.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections